# Stop Rack session setting a cookie for all pages

Tags: ruby, session, cookies, sinatra, rack

In my Sinatra app I am using rack sessions

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => ENV['SECRET']
```

It seems to be setting a cookie for every page load, even if I am not setting anything in a session. Is there a way to change it to only set a cookie if a session is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rack::Session::Cookie` keeps sessions into a marshaled Ruby `Hash`.

Basically it is marshaling your session and persist it into cookies.

And it does not care your session is an empty `Hash`,
it will be marshaled and persisted into cookies anyway.

Do you really need to keep your sessions in cookies?

Perhaps `use Rack::Session::Pool` to keep your sessions in a memory pool?
Then it will set a cookie only once.

Comment: Actually, Rack::Session::Pool will set a cookie every time the session is loaded (read from **or** written to), unless the `:skip` or `:defer` (and not `:renew`) session options are `true`. So even if you don't change your session data and simply just read it, Rack will still send the same old session id in a cookie back to the client for every request. The HTTP header to set this session ID is typically about 100-150 bytes, so it's minimal overhead compared to a marshaled object which could be several kilobytes.